# get last records with different values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a sql query with MySQL.

Here is my table Trace. Inside I have records with id column, data column, date column and transition column :

```
Id    Data  Date        Transition
1     775   2016-05-10  34
2     775   2016-05-11  35
3     775   2016-05-23  34 
4     775   2016-05-24  35
```

I would like to get the id(s) of the last double record(s) of the Data 775 where transition is 34 or 35. 
In the exemple I gave it would be the records 3 and 4.
But if id 4 does not exist, it would give me 3 only.
And if the there is only one set of record with 34 and 35 for this data 775 (So just ids 1 and 2), it would give me nothing.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you add the result as data too, instead of just an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, Data, Date, Transition
FROM mytable
WHERE Id IN (SELECT MAX(Id)
             FROM mytable
             GROUP BY Data, Transition
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```